# Получить строку по индексу в DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf

Пытаюсь сделать запись содержимого `DataGrid` в html-таблицу.

Нашел [пример кода](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16008570/6641468), но для `DataGridView`.

```
private StringBuilder DataGridtoHTML(DataGridView dg)
{
  StringBuilder strB = new StringBuilder();
  //create html & table
  strB.AppendLine("<html><body><center><" + 
                "table border='1' cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0'>");
  strB.AppendLine("<tr>");
  //cteate table header
  for (int i = 0; i < dg.Columns.Count; i++)
  {
     strB.AppendLine("<td align='center' valign='middle'>" + 
                    dg.Columns[i].HeaderText + "</td>");
   }
  //create table body
  strB.AppendLine("<tr>");
  for (int i = 0; i < dg.Rows.Count; i++)
  {
    strB.AppendLine("<tr>");
    foreach (DataGridViewCell dgvc in dg.Rows[i].Cells)
    {
        strB.AppendLine("<td align='center' valign='middle'>" + 
                        dgvc.Value.ToString() + "</td>");
    }
    strB.AppendLine("</tr>");

}
//table footer & end of html file
strB.AppendLine("</table></center></body></html>");
return strB;}
```

Проблема в том, что у `DataGrid` нет свойства Rows как у `DataGridView`.

Подскажите, как перебрать таким же образом строки для `DataGrid`?

Comment: если это `WPF` то вам намного проще использовать связывание данных и представлять в html именно их.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var rowIndex = dataGrid.SelectedIndex;
var row = (DataGridRow)dataGrid.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(selectedIndex);
```

или

```
dataGrid.SelectedIndex = 3;
var selectedRow= (DataRowView)dataGrid.SelectedItem;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
   for (int i = 0; i < dataGrid.Items.Count; i++)
    {
        DataGridRow row = (DataGridRow)dataGrid.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(i);
    }
```